# Wordpress Customizations Dont work except in admin view

Tags: php, wordpress, function, api, customization

I have a problem, I used the following set of code in functions.php to make changes on the Customization API. I have my customize features implemented but when I use them it only works for me, the admin. Any change I make like colors or pictures doesn't show up on the public site. Only admins.

[image]
In public its not green and have the defualt pictures

Any help or is there some designed code for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, Wordpress just decided to fix itself somewhat and I dont know how.

Anyway, It works now.